# No nontrivial homogeneous polynomial vanishing on open subset of unit sphere $S^{n-1}$?

Tags: polynomials

Let $S^{n-1} = \{x: \|x\|^2 = 1\}$, the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

In an article I'm reading it is mentioned that if the subset $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ contains an open subset of $S^{n-1}$ (I assume in the relative topology), then no nontrivial homogeneous polynomial vanishes on $A$.

It is stated without a proof or any references. Is this a well know fact that is easy to prove? Can anyone point me to where I can find a proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U=A\cap S^{n-1}$. If a polynomial $P$ vanishes on $U$ the, since it is homogeneous, it vanishes in $\mathbb{R}^+U$. But this is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. If $P$ vanishes on an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, it is the null polynomial.

Comment: What do you mean by $Y$ and $\mathbb{R}^{+} U$?

Comment: @Robo I meant $U$, not $Y$. $\mathbb{R}^+U=\{tu\,|\,t\in\mathbb{R}^+\wedge u\in U\}$.

Comment: Of course! Thanks!